# particles moving instead of staying still while growing

Tags: particles, physics, vertex-weights

I made a field with grass on it. The grass is set as hair particles.
I used a vertex weight proximity modifier on the field to make grass grow in a specific direction, growing from the middle of the field to its extremities.

But when the grass appears, it changes position instead of staying still.

I join a video to make it more clear. https://youtu.be/w0cVjsNpsYY

I hope anyone could help me.
Have a great day all

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.